# Slow installation of 22.04 under WSL

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (Jammy) for WSL has a new installer (called the "Out of Box Experience" by Canonical) that provides a graphical UI to walk users through the installation.  However, it is *substantially* slower than the older text-based install that other WSL distributions (including 20.04) use.  For comparison:

- *22.04 Jammy:*  ~ 1 minute 30 seconds for all screens, even just accepting the defaults (other than username/password)
- *20.04 Focal:*  ~ 20 seconds (9 seconds + however long it takes to type your username and password twice)

This probably isn't an issue for most people, but I like to "spin up" a 22.04 (or other distribution) quickly, try something out, then throw it away with `wsl --unregister Ubuntu-22.04`.

Jammy's installer goes through multiple steps, only some of which seem "useful" compared to the previous installer:

- *"Unpacking the distro"* -- 11-12 seconds on my relatively fast NVMe drive.
- *"Almost done. The installer will require your attention soon."* -- ~14 seconds
- *"We are almost done - Just a few steps to be completed in the main installer window.  Can we quit this one and go there?"*
- A language selection screen
- The username/password screen
- *"Advanced Setup"* where mount options can be set
- *"Applying Changes"* -- The biggest issue, since it takes more than 30 seconds, and says it may take longer if the network connection is slow.

  It's really not clear what's going on in this step since it shouldn't even need an internet connection to apply changes to a local WSL installation of Ubuntu.

By comparison, Focal needs only about 10 seconds to complete the first step (unpacking), at which point it is ready to accept the username/password, and then it's done.

Is there any way to speed up the Jammy OOBE/Installer, perhaps by skipping certain steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu and Ubuntu 22.04 now ship with the OOBE disabled by default so install time has gone down to be similar to Focal.

A newer OOBE was made for Ubuntu (Preview) that is much faster.

Comment: Excellent -- Thanks for the update!  I'll give the Preview OOBE a try.  What's the best spot for feedback if needed?

Comment: Github! https://github.com/ubuntu/WSL/issues

Answer (score 1):

***Obsoleted answer left for historical reasons only***

*Happily not needed any longer since, as 
[@EduGómezEscandell points out](https://askubuntu.com/a/1439783/1165986) the OOBE has been disabled in the latest 22.04 releases on the Store.  Leaving it here for posterity in case in does come in handy for someone, but it's doubtful.*

---

The 22.04 OOBE GUI installer can be disabled with:

```
ubuntu2204.exe install --ui=none
```

This will revert to the "normal", text-based WSL installation method.  The installation time is on par with Focal (ever-so-slightly-faster, even) -- Around 8 seconds to install/unpack, then you are ready to enter your username/password and launch the distro.