# How to return to default user after switching to root in Ubuntu on WSL?

Tags: command-line, root, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL on Windows 11 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa).

During the installation process, I think I entered the command `ubuntu --install` (in VSCode), but I ran into an issue during the installation.  The terminal opened, asking for a Linux user and password, but then it closed as some other application started or something.

Since I never got the chance to set my default user's password, I opened CMD, and, if I remember correctly, used the command `ubuntu config --default-user root`.  Then I returned to the Ubuntu shell and entered a command to reset my Linux password.

At this point I had not even used my VSCode.  However, when I open VSCode, it still seems to be in the root user's account.

I used `mkdir` to create a folder without realizing I was still in root, as shown below:

```
root@Lokrheim:~/folder#
```

When I type `exit`, the shell just closes, as if it is exiting the application rather than the root user's login.  No matter what I do, my VSCode still remains as a root user.

How can I access my non-root user in Ubuntu on WSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there was an issue upon restarting as the shell had opened asking for a Linux user and password but the shell closed as some other application started or something

It sounds like you have an aborted installation, which probably left you *without* a default user at all.  In this case, WSL defaults to using the root user (regardless of the distribution).

###### Option 1:  Reinstall Ubuntu on WSL

If you've just recently installed and *don't have any files* that you don't mind losing in Ubuntu, then the best solution is going to be to simply reinstall the distribution so that it completes properly.

To do so, open a regular (non-Admin) PowerShell terminal, and ...

```
wsl --unregister Ubuntu
ubuntu.exe
```

(Side-note:  If this was Ubuntu 22.04, I'd recommend using either `ubuntu.exe install --gui=none` or `ubuntu2204.exe install --gui=none` as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1417507/1165986).)

That will pretty-quickly complete the installation (since it doesn't actually have to re-download the Store package) and get you back to the point where it asks for a default username and password.

###### Option 2: Recreate user manually

If you *do* have files and need to recover without a reinstall, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1360294/1165986) and look for the  section on *"Creating a new "default" WSL user without reinstalling"*.  Also use the next step (*Setting the default WSL user*) to reset the default after creating one.